# Google Maps add Location

Tags: php, javascript

How can I get the location that the user has clicked on the map via js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a callback function I used for a drop event on the map canvas once:

```
function placeDroppedMarker()
{
    var locale = new google.maps.LatLng(mouseLat, mouseLng);

    document.getElementById('map-lat').value = mouseLat;
    document.getElementById('map-lng').value = mouseLng;
    document.getElementById('map-icon-input').value = SelectedIcon;

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: locale,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
        });
        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                "http://www.twulogin.org/ourride/wp-content/themes/spectrum/images/" + SelectedIcon + ".png", 
                new google.maps.Size(37,37), 
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(16,37),
                new google.maps.Size(37,37)
        );
        marker.setIcon(image);

        map.setCenter(locale); 
}
```

You have to set an event listener (in your map init function) like this to get mouseLat and mouseLng:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {
     mouseLat = event.latLng.lat();
     mouseLng = event.latLng.lng();
});
```

Where map is your google map.

The full working example is at:
http://www.ourride.org/?page_id=238